# How to check the variables of an Object are Empty or NULL in JAVA?

Tags: java, null, initialization, java-11, isnullorempty

How to check `variables of Objects` are `empty or NULL` in JAVA?

```
Employee employee = repository.getEmployee(id).orElseGet(null);
if (employee == null) {
   employee = new Employee();
   employee.id(1);
   employee.name("Thirumal");
   employee.mobile("+91-8973-697-871");
   repository.save(employee);
}
```

Instead of `NULL`, I  am trying to create an object `new Employee()`

```
Employee employee = repository.getEmployee(id).orElseGet(new Employee());
if (employee.isEmpty()) { //--------- How to do ????????
   employee = new Employee();
   employee.id(1);
   employee.name("Thirumal");
   employee.mobile("+91-8973-697-871");
   repository.save(employee);
}
```

How to check the `member of objects` are `empty/NULL`?

Comment: Depends on what it means for an `Employee` and its members to be empty.

Comment: Add a flag to your `Employee` class and change it after setting values?

Comment: use `||` symbol as logical or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add that `isEmpty` method to `Employee` class and implement it there, or use a [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern) instead of doing `new Employee()`.

As to what you are actually trying to do in your code, I suggest to do it like that instead:

```java
Employee employee = repository.getEmployee(id).orElseGet(() -> {
   Employee emp = new Employee();
   emp.id(1);
   emp.name("Thirumal");
   emp.mobile("+91-8973-697-871");
   return repository.save(emp);
});
```